# Why am I getting these errors with disqus?

Tags: disqus

Here is my code that includes the disqus block:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function disqus_show_comment_form()
        {
            document.getElementById("disqus_thread").style.display = "none";
        }

        /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = "allisonchristiansen"; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
        var disqus_developer = 0; // developer mode is off
        var disqus_identifier = "myidentifier";
        var disqus_url = "http://myurl";
        var disqus_title = "mytitle";
        var disqus_category_id = "1140640";

        // DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement("script"); dsq.type = "text/javascript"; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js";
            (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Here are the errors I'm getting in the browser (chrome)

```
GET http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js  lounge.load.js:1
GET http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js  lounge.load.js:1
GET http://juggler.services.disqus.com/event.js?thread_slug=deployment_calculat…forum_id=1118986&user_id=myid&imp=1h1uai3l6eine&prev_imp=1h1h8bp2ma0m1  common.js:6
GET http://juggler.services.disqus.com/event.js?major_version=metadata&internal…forum_id=1118986&user_id=myid&imp=1h1uai3l6eine&prev_imp=1h1h8bp2ma0m1  common.js:6
```

The disqus block is working, but I want to remove these errors from the browser if possible.

Thanks.